# How to graphically represent Meta characters

Tags: key-bindings, help, keystrokes

Given that the variable `x` contains the numeric representation of the key "Control-Z", say

```
(setq x ?\C-z),
```

one may graphically represent its contents by issuing the command

```
(char-to-string x),
```

producing the usual representation of "Control-Z", namely "^Z".  I would like to acheive a similar effect in case `x` contained the numeric representation of "Meta-Z", namely

```
(setq x ?\M-z).
```

However my system represents "Meta-Z" as the number 134217850, and `(char-to-string x)` now causes the error `(wrong-type-argument characterp 134217850)`.   I am aware that the graphical representation of "Meta-Z" is not as standard as
for "Control-Z", since the latter is part of the ASCII code while the former isn't, but anything legible, such as "M-Z" would be better than the big number 134217850.

My question is thus: which standard elisp function should I use in order to transform numerical representations of Meta characters into a legible string?

Comment: You could try `(key-description [?\M-z])` (but it has to be a vector, not a single number).

Comment: @wvxvw, thanks very much!  Should you decide to turn your comment into an answer, I'd be glad to accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properly speaking, `?\C-z` is the *read syntax* of the character. Internally, the Lisp object is an integer. Nonetheless, characters in strings may have different character codes [2]. In other words, a similar read syntax does not necessarily produce the same Lisp object.

You can see in the following example that the character codes are different: `134217818` and `218`.

```
ELISP> ?\M-Z
134217818
ELISP> "\M-Z"
"\332"
ELISP> ?\332
218
```

Characters inserted in text must be in the range of 0 to 4194303. Extra characters, typed using modifier keys, are used to represent keyboard inputs. [1]

In summary, you cannot use a string (*read syntax*) to represent a meta character. For a conversion function, look at [3].

```
(single-key-description ?\M-z)
```

#### References

- [1] [Elisp manual, section 2.3.3. Character Type](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Type.html#Character-Type).
- [2] [Elisp manual, section 2.3.8.3 Nonprinting Characters in Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Nonprinting-Characters.html#Nonprinting-Characters).
- [3] [Elisp manual, section 24.5 Describing Characters for Help Messages](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Describing-Characters.html#Describing-Characters).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Based on your answered, specifically [3], I found exactly what I was looking for: `(single-key-description 134217850)`